# Vulkan/OpenGL subpasses that fetch more than single fragment

Tags: opengl-es, vulkan, framebuffer

So, Vulkan introduced subpasses and opengl implelemts similar behaviour with ARM_framebuffer_fetch

In the past, I have used framebuffer_fetch successfully for tonemapping post-effect shaders.

Back then the limitation was that one could only read the contents of the framebuffer at the location of the currently rendered fragment.

Now, what I wonder is whether there is any way by now in Vulkan (or even OpenGL ES) to read from multiple locations (for example to implement a blur kernel) without having a tiled hardware to store/load to RAM.

In theory I guess it should be possible, the first pass wpuld just need to render slightly larger than the blur subpass, based on kernel size (so for example if kernel size was 4 pixels then the tile resolved would need to be 4 pixels smaller than the in-tile buffer sizes) and some pixels would have to be rendered redundantly (on the overlaps of tiles).

Now, is there a way to do that?
I seem to recall having seen some Vulkan instruction related to subpasses that would allow to define the support size (which sounded like what I’m looking for now) but I can’t recall where I saw that.
So my questions:

1. With Vulkan on a mobile tiled renderer architecture, is it possible to forward-render some geometry and the render a full-screen blur over it, all within a single in-tile pass (without the hardware having to store the result of the intermediate pass to ram first and then load the texture from ram when bluring)? If so, how?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, can it also be done in OpenGL ES?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. Vulkan subpasses still have the 1:1 fragment-to-pixel association requirements.